# Java mail works in an internal mail server but other one has issues

Tags: jakarta-mail

Sending mail with attachment works using a specific internal mail server, but not with another mail server.

In the actual Production environment , it uses a different mail server, Currently emails are getting send without attachments using this mail server.

But when I send email with attachment using this mail server, it completes the Transport.send ()   , I am trying to print the stack trace of any exception.  but it does not print any exceptions...

Looks like no exception occured but no mail also got send.

Can someone please help...

Thanks.
us

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on session debugging to get the protocol trace (see the JavaMail FAQ) to make sure the message is getting sent properly.

Are you sending the message to another internal address?  Possibly the recipient's mail server is rejecting the message, perhaps because it won't accept attachments at all or perhaps because it won't accept the type of attachment you're sending.  Or maybe it thinks your message looks like spam.